# emacs font setting does not load at start

Tags: emacs, fonts

I put my font setting at a separate *font_settings.el* file and load it with:

```
(load-library "font_settings")
```

at the end of init.el.

But every time I start Emacs, emacs seems not load the settings.
I have to eval-buffer to evaluate init.el to let it work.

So it seems the settings are OK but loading sequence or the way I load it is not right...

Any thoughts?

The code of font_settings.el is here (too long):

http://pastebin.com/ExpY1mTy

Comment: Do you have some customizations too?  These might override your settings.

Comment: Er... yes, I find in my .emacs file a line accidentally added to modify the overall fonts... After I remove that line, everything is fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Is `font_settings.el` in your `load-path`? If not, put it there or add the directory that contains it:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/the/full/directory/name/my-directory/")
```

See the Emacs manual, node [Lisp Libraries](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html).

You can check whether the library was actually loaded by using `C-h v load-history`.  (Alternatively, you can check whether something that the library defines actually gets defined.)

Comment: Yes, it is. Otherwise it won't be loaded when "eval-buffer" the init.el file.

Comment: Is it loaded? Check as I described. Is your `init.el` file loaded? Provide more information or you will just keep people guessing wildly, and they will be less apt to help you. ;-)

Comment: Yes, it is loaded. Both init.el and font_settings.el

Comment: But not all settings in the font_settings.el take effect.

Comment: The font type works, the size doesn't. Only by eval-buffer init.el again, the size will take effect.

Comment: Then show the specifics. Show code. It's not our job to guess what is in `font-settings.el` or how Emacs is interacting with it. This question risks being closed as unclear. My advice is to *specify* the problem, so people can help you without wasting their time guessing.

Comment: Er... yes, I find in my .emacs file a line accidentally added to modify the overall fonts... After I remove that line, everything is fine. Thank you for your time.